# Atmospheric refraction - large distances

Tags: refraction

In the webpage here [Mirages and other atomospheric optic phenomena (gsu.edu)](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/atmos/mirage.html)  it says the atmospheric refraction can project images for *very large distance*s. How many kilometers could be those very large distances? The atmospheric refraction could perhaps project images for distances equal or more than 1.000 km over the sea? Any advice is welcome.

Comment: Your link shows distant ships and islands being imaged. Those are likely over a kilometer away. There is also an image of the Sun. Light from the Sun traveled almost all the way to Earth, when the atmosphere diffracted it into a new direction. You are seeing an image projected from over the horizon in some cases.

Comment: Exactly, distant islands. Does atmospheric refraction can image, let's say, islands that in normal conditions far away, over the horizon?